# Dates in stripe customer properties

Tags: date-format, stripe-payments

I am not sure what format the `current_period_start` `current_period_end` fields are in when stripe returns me a customer object. I am trying to show my user when their next billing date is after they have subscribed to one of my plans. How are we supposed to parse these values?

[image: Customer object]

Comment: Yay! Another person who uses Stripe!

Comment: The solution is to convert this as the format is in Unix Time